# SVM in R (e1071): Give more recent data higher influence (weights for support vector machine?)

Tags: r, svm

I'm working with Support Vector Machines from the `e1071` package in `R`. This is my first project using SVM.

I have a dataset containing order histories of ~1k customers over 1 year and I want to predict costumer purchases. For every customer I have the information if a certain item (out of ~50) was bought or not in a certain week (for 52 weeks aka 1 yr).

My goal is to predict next month's purchases for every single customer.

I believe that a purchase let's say 1 month ago is more meaningful for my prediction than a purchase 10 months ago.

My question is now how I can give more recent data a higher impact? There is a 'weight' option in the svm-function but I'm not sure how to use it.

Anyone who can give me a hint? Would be much appreciated!

That's my code

```
      # Fit model using Support Vecctor Machines
      # install.packages("e1071")
      library(e1071)

      response <- train[,5];  # purchases
      formula <- response ~ .;

      tuned.svm <- tune.svm(train, response, probability=TRUE,
                  gamma=10^(-6:-3), cost=10^(1:2));   
      gamma.k <- tuned.svm$best.parameter[[1]];
      cost.k <- tuned.svm$best.parameter[[2]];
      svm.model <- svm(formula, data = train, 
                   type='eps-regression', probability=TRUE, 
                   gamma=gamma.k, cost=cost.k);
      svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, test, probability=TRUE);
```

Side notes: I'm fitting a model for every single customer. Also, since I'm interested in the probability, that customer *i* buys item *j* in week *k*, I put

```
probability=TRUE
```

[click here to see a sccreenshot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YrHO.png)

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about your dataset, perhaps with an example of the first ten rows?

Comment: @rwp I added a screenshot in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Weights option in the R SVM Model is more towards assigning weights to solve the problem of imbalance classes. its class.Weights parameter and is used to assign weightage to different classes 1/0 in a biased dataset.

To answer your question: to give more weightage in a SVM Model for recent data, a simple trick in absence of an ibuild weight functionality at observation level is to repeat the recent columns (i.e. create duplicate rows for recent data) hence indirectly assigning them higher weight

Answer (score 0):

Try this package: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=WeightSVM

It uses a modified version of 'libsvm' and is able to deal with instance weighting. You can assign higher weights to recent data.

For example. You have simulated data (x,y)

```
x <- seq(0.1, 5, by = 0.05)
y <- log(x) + rnorm(x, sd = 0.2)
```

This is an unweighted SVM:

```
model1 <- wsvm(x, y, weight = rep(1,99))
```

[Blue dots is the unweighted SVM and do not fit the first instance well. We want to put more weights on the first several instances.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9qDd.png)

So we can use a weighted SVM:

```
model2 <- wsvm(x, y, weight = seq(99,1,length.out = 99))
```

[Green dots is the weighted SVM and fit the first instance better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgsQA.png)